# Como posso converter o tipo Date em String ? (Linguagem Java)

Tags: java, string, data

```
public class Passageiro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Viagem passageiro = new Viagem();

        passageiro.nomePassageiro = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o seu nome:");
        passageiro.dataEmbarque = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a data da sua viagem:");
        passageiro.destino = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o seu destino:");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, passageiro.exibirReserva());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem algum formato específico? Geralmente é só usar `toString()`.

Comment: @bigown Formato normal de datas mesmo (dia / mês / ano)

Comment: Deve ter outras duplicatas. Formato normal é muito amplo, o que é normal para você não é normal para outra pessoa. Programação é detalhe.

Comment: Então, o exercício não pede nenhum formato específico, acho que pode ser qualquer um a escolha.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());`